# Ping multiple different ip addresses at the same time

Tags: ruby, windows, command-line, command-prompt

I need to ping multiple Ip addresses at the same time. I know of programs that can do this well (colasoft), however, I need the results to be available to my ruby script. I'm thinking multiple command prompts is the only way but I am hoping to stay away from that. **What are some other ways to ping multiple addresses, gets their results back separately, and this 'way' has to be able to be initialized and analyzed by a ruby script.**

Comment: You would have to use multiple threads to do this, which is I guess multiple `cmd` instances. Also, having multiple pings would slow the network down creating inaccurate readings

Comment: Look at http://askubuntu.com/q/413367. But, you should have been able to find that with a search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
ips = ['8.8.8.8', '127.0.0.1']

threads = ips.map do |ip|
  Thread.new { Thread.current[:result] = `ping -q -c 1 #{ip}` }
end

threads.each do |thread|
  thread.join
  puts "#{thread[:result]} \n\n"
end
```

Example output:

```
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8): 56 data bytes

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 28.667/28.667/28.667/0.000 ms


PING 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1): 56 data bytes

--- 127.0.0.1 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100.0% packet loss
```

Comment: Exactly the output I was looking for! Thanks a lot